# IdentityServer3 Customize Logo on Login Page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, identityserver3

I am integrating IdentityServer3 for SSO in my web applications.

For one of the application I want to show logo in login page based on query string parameter
e.g.

www.domain.com/?site=site1  -- Show logo1

www.domain.com/?site=site2  -- Show logo 2

SSO link is www.domain.com/sso

I am using DefaultViewService for my login page (_login.html). I am not getting how to get "site" parameter in login page?

Please suggest the possible solutions.

Comment: Did you every figure this out?

Comment: Not exactly, but changed the logic to solve this with other way.